# Java changing Endpoint parameter (programmatically)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket

I'm new to websockets and I thought I'd understand how to configure it programmatically first.

```
public class T extends Endpoint{

@Override
public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
    ..
}

}
```

Is it possible to modify the `Endpoint` class to add new parameters? Say I wanna add a new parameter for username

```
@Override
public Set<ServerEndpointConfig> getEndpointConfigs(Set<Class<? extends myCustomEndpoint>> endpointClasses) {
   ..
}
```

Is it enough to just change the `Set<Class extends myCustomEndpoint>> endPoints` to my custom class?

```
public abstract class myCustomEndPoint{

 ...

 public void onOpen(String username, Session session, EndpointConfig config) { .. }

 ...

}
```

Comment: I think it is AB question

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I think he is talking about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/361950) and I kind of agree: what is the actual problem you're trying to resolve?

Comment: How is it logical? what should be passed to username when connection opens?

Comment: I'm not trying to resolve anything. I'm asking If it's possible to add a new parameter to ``onOpen``